# How to add AWS SSL certificate to DNN site

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, dotnetnuke

We’ve bind our DNN site to http (80) URL.
URL has AWS SSL certificate.
Problem is when we navigate page to page https change into http.
(But all pages can be access by https://.....)

We tried IIS redirect binding. – Not worked.
(Pages are redirecting to endless loop)

Then we tried redirect using web config. – Not worked.
(500 server error occurred)

Anyone has idea to how to fix this issue.

Comment: This may be off-topic. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable SSL in the Portal Settings.

```
Admin > Site Settings > Advanced Settings > SSL Settings
```

There you need to set "SSL Enabled?" to true.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried that. It did not work for us. It this something handle from aws side ?

Comment: I don't know. I've never worked with AWS certificates before. Did you install all the Intermediate and server certificates also (if needed). And configured IIS https://www.digicert.com/csr-ssl-installation/iis-7.htm